# How do you fix "No Trust List Installed" error on a Cisco 7942G VoIP Phone?

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip

I have a 7942G. I'm trying to connect it to Asterisk.

Looking at Settings -> Status -> Status Messages, I see this:

```
Error Updating Locale
SEP############.cnf.xml
No Trust List Installed
```

I'm only concerned with the No Trust List Installed error and not the Locale issue right now. I'll worry about the Locales later.

Does anybody know what to do about this?

UPDATE
I started over and the phone status is this:

```
Error Updating Locale
Error Updating Locale
SEP############.cnf.xml
No Trust List Installed
```

And I found this in the TFTP server logs:

```
May 22 20:40:16 nas01 dnsmasq-tftp[481]: file CTLSEP############.tlv not found
May 22 20:40:16 nas01 dnsmasq-tftp[481]: file ITLSEP############.tlv not found
May 22 20:40:16 nas01 dnsmasq-tftp[481]: file ITLFile.tlv not found
May 22 20:40:19 nas01 dnsmasq-tftp[481]: file English_United_States/mk-sip.jar not found
May 22 20:40:21 nas01 dnsmasq-tftp[481]: file United_States/g3-tones.xml not found
```

Comment: Have you tried google? https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/unified-ip-phone-7900-series/113500-trust-list.html

Comment: Of course. I only use Stack Exchange forums after countless hours of blood sweat and trears, attempting all possibilities I can imagine by myself. That link is for CUCM and CUCME, not Asterisk. I don't have access to CUCM/CUCME. It recommends to delete ITL files so the phone will request a new ITL from CUCM/CUCME. That would probably work if I was working with CUCM/CUCME but unfortunately I'm not.

Comment: It is same. You need disable like described in that article.

Comment: Asterisk not deal with cisco files. You can use tftp if you want.

Comment: Thanks @arheops. You say I need to disable. I don't see the word "disable" in that entire article. What do you mean I need to disable? And I am using TFTP. Not sure what you meant about that either. Could you please clarify?